# JOLT: Merge specific data from JSON array using id key and leave other arrays untouch

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

I previously have this issue of merging data into another one to avoid duplicates and make a cleaner version of the JSON. I got a solution in here that worked like a charm for a while but after I got more information arrayed inside the JSON things got a little bit tricky.

I have this array:

```
{
  "clubhouse": [
    {
      "id": "01",
      "statusId": "ok",
      "stateid": "2",
      "nationalities": [
        {
          "nationalityid": "1"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "2"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "3"
        }
      ],
      "TypeId": "3",
      "investors": [
        {
          "investor": {
            "id": "1234",
            "gender": "01"
          },
          "inamount": "1500000",
          "ratio": "12"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "01",
      "statusId": "ok",
      "stateid": "2",
"nationalities": [
        {
          "nationalityid": "1"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "2"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "3"
        }
      ],
      "TypeId": "3",
      "investors": [
        {
          "investor": {
            "id": "4321",
            "gender": "02"
          },
          "inamount": "1700000",
          "ratio": "12"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "02",
      "statusId": "ok",
      "stateid": "2",
"nationalities": [
        {
          "nationalityid": "3"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "4"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "5"
        }
      ],

      "TypeId": "3",
      "investors": [
        {
          "investor": {
            "id": "1333",
            "gender": "01"
          },
          "inamount": "1500000",
          "ratio": "12"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "03",
      "statusId": "ok",
      "stateid": "5",

"nationalities": [
        {
          "nationalityid": "3"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "4"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "5"
        }
      ],

      "TypeId": "3",
      "investors": [
        {
          "investor": {
            "id": "", 
            "gender": ""
          },
          "inamount": "",
          "ratio": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "02",
      "statusId": "ok",
      "stateid": "2",
"nationalities": [
        {
          "nationalityid": "3"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "4"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "5"
        }
      ],
      "TypeId": "3",
      "investors": [
        {
          "investor": {
            "id": "1334",
            "gender": "02"
          },
          "inamount": "1900000",
          "ratio": "12"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I was using this JOLT but it doesnt work with the nationalities,since it loses the array they are in.

```
[
  {
   // group by "id" values to create separate objects 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "@(1,id).&",
          "investors": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "@": "@(4,id).&3[&4].&" // &3 -> going 3 levels up to grab literal "investors", [&4] -> going 4 levels up the tree in order to reach the indexes of "clubhouse" array, & -> replicate the leaf node values for the current key-value pair
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of "null" values
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  },
  {
    // pick only the first components from the repeated values populated within the arrays 
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE",
        "investors": "MANY"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of object labels
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

What I need to get is something like this:

```
{
  "clubhouse": [
    {
      "id": "01",
      "statusId": "ok",
      "stateid": "2",
            "nationalities": [
        {
          "nationalityid": "1"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "2"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "3"
        }
      ],
      "TypeId": "3",
      "investors": [
        {
          "investor": {
            "id": "1234",
            "gender": "01"
          },
          "inamount": "1500000",
          "ratio": "12"
        },
        {
          "investor": {
            "id": "4321",
            "gender": "02"
          },
          "inamount": "1700000",
          "ratio": "12"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "02",
      "statusId": "ok",
      "stateid": "2",
      "nationalities": [
        {
          "nationalityid": "3"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "4"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "5"
        }
      ],
      "TypeId": "3",
      "investors": [
        {
          "investor": {
            "id": "1333",
            "gender": "01"
          },
          "inamount": "1500000",
          "ratio": "12"
        },
        {
          "investor": {
            "id": "1334",
            "gender": "02"
          },
          "inamount": "1900000",
          "ratio": "12"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "03",
      "statusId": "ok",
      "stateid": "5",
      "nationalities": [
        {
          "nationalityid": "3"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "4"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "5"
        }
      ],
      "TypeId": "3",
      "investors": [
        {
          "investor": {
            "id": "",
            "gender": ""
          },
          "inamount": "",
          "ratio": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's a typo.

Comment: The problem is that the array nationalityid (typo nationalitysid) brings me the array as many times as investor I have, and I only need it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rearrange the first **shift** transformation by adding a new object tagged `"nationalities"` which has one level reduced identifiers compared to the already existing object tagged `"investors"`, and the existing **cardinality** transformation would already pick only the first array among repeated identical `"nationalities"` arrays if the remaining specs are kept as they are, such as the below one

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "@(1,id).&",
          "nationalities": {
            "*": {
              "@": "@(3,id).&2[&3][]"
            }
          },
          "investors": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "@": "@(4,id).&3[&4].&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: I try this a couple of times, it works like a charm when I have more than one nationality but if I have only one the array "nationalities": [{}] comes like this, "nationalities":{} and the platform rejects it

Comment: Adding a `[]` to the rightend of the value identifier of `"nationalities"` object will handle the case @Sinuers . Just edited the answer.